# Split a long row into multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

First time posting - any feedback is appreciated. New user in python trying to get a scraper going to get national gas prices from AAA. Question comes on how to convert numpy to pandas to keep rows - as of now it's converting to DF and puts all data in one row.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://gasprices.aaa.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}  # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
result = requests.get(url,headers = headers)

data = []
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml') #passing source variable into bs class to create an object
rows = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table-mob"}) #parse box info
headers = []

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

for row in rows:
    headers = row.find_all('th')
    headers = [ele.text.strip() for ele in headers]
    headers.append([ele for ele in headers if ele])


data = np.array(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Current output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqh6h.png)

Goal is to have it like this:

```
Current Avg.    $2.79   $3.11   $3.36   $3.01   $2.45                  
Yesterday Avg.  $2.79   $3.11   $3.36   $3.01   $2.45 
Week Ago Avg.   $2.75   $3.07   $3.32   $3.00   $2.42 
Month Ago Avg.  $2.69   $3.03   $3.28   $3.02   $2.33 
Year Ago Avg.   $2.87   $3.17   $3.42   $3.17   $2.43
```

Comment: How does the data look like? can you post a sample? the link `https://gasprices.aaa.com` does not seem to be an API or `CSV`

Comment: The first part of the program is a scraper from gasprices.aaa.com. See Current output picture for what the DF to CSV looks like

Answer (score 0):

#### `np.reshape`

- [**`np.reshape`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) turns the values in `df` into a **6 by 5** array, unwrapping downward first.
- `idx, *dat` is unpacking the first row from the resulting array to the name `idx` and the rest into a list named `dat`. [Variable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

---

```
idx, *dat = np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (6, -1), order='F')
pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=idx).T

                     0       1       2       3       4
Current Avg.    $2.793  $3.107  $3.362  $3.010  $2.449
Yesterday Avg.  $2.792  $3.105  $3.360  $3.010  $2.449
Week Ago Avg.   $2.749  $3.068  $3.321  $3.004  $2.417
Month Ago Avg.  $2.689  $3.027  $3.280  $3.018  $2.332
Year Ago Avg.   $2.871  $3.167  $3.416  $3.168  $2.432
```

---

Similarly

```
idx, *dat = np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (6, -1), order='F')
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(idx, dat))).T
```

---

If `df.to_numpy` doesn't work, try:

```
idx, *dat = np.reshape(df.values, (6, -1), order='F')
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(idx, dat))).T
```

Comment: TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 
pd.version.0.19.2

Comment: @PashBab I've updated the post.  I think that will work.  If it doesn't then something more sinister is going on.  Like you may have overwritten `pd.DataFrame` or `np.reshape`

Comment: It worked! Mind linking literature about your answer - I don't completely understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: Since this data was already in order and all had to be done was to produce a new row every 6th element, a simple data = np.reshape(data,(5,6)) was sufficient. Thank you for such a full answer with references.